# how to do live streaming in iphone from the server?

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming

I want to broadcast the video from the local server into the iPhone.
I only get link which is coming from the web-service with any extension of the video.

Video can be in any format..

LIKE :`@"avi",@"wmv",@"rmvb",@"flv",@"f4v",@"swf",@"mkv",@"dat",@"vob",@"mts",@"ogg",@"mpg",@"wma"`

so,which player is better for my app.

1)`MPMovieplaycontroller` or

2)`AVPlayer controller`

Please help me.

Comment: Thnaks sunny....but i do not want to use uiwebview..i can use only MPMovieplaycontroller or AVPlayer controller

Comment: But MPMovieplaycontroller or AVPlayer  will not support all the format

Comment: is there any another player which supported all kind of format???but do not want to use web-view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the MPMoviePlayerController docs:**

*Supported Formats*

This class supports any movie or audio files that already play correctly on an iPod or iPhone. This includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4,.mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:

1. H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
2. MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile) If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio

You have to use 3rd Party libraries for your mentioned case

Answer (score 0):

The built in media player won't support any of those formats.

Your only option is really a third party library like VLCKit. I've never used it, but it likely supports more formats that you require:
https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/

Answer (score 0):

Though I've never tried before, but I am sure you will get help from this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH101-SW2).

There is a nice discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291691/implementation-of-http-live-streaming-in-ios) about your problem. Sorry for not giving a direct answer. Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This [AVPlayer SDK DOC](https://github.com/iMoreApps/AVPlayer-for-iOS-Demo)  may be helpful for you. But as per your requirement you have go for third part or your custom implementations.